# python -c and `while`

Tags: python, windows, linux, command-line

Is there a way to loop in `while` if you start the script with `python -c`?  This doesn't seem to be related to platform or python version...

**Linux**

```
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$ python -c "import os;while (True):    os.system('ls')"
  File "<string>", line 1
    import os;while (True):    os.system('ls')
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$ uname -a
Linux Hotcoffee 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:00:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$
```

**Windows**

```
C:\Users\mike_pennington>python -c "import os;while True: os.system('dir')"
  File "<string>", line 1
    import os;while True: os.system('dir')
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Users\mike_pennington>python -V
Python 2.7.2

C:\Users\mike_pennington>
```

I have tried removing parenthesis in the `while` statement, but nothing seems to make this run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
python -c $'import subprocess\nwhile True: subprocess.call(["ls"])'
```

would work (note the `$'...'` and the `\n`).

But it could be that it only works under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) - I am not sure...

Comment: `os.system()` is obviously not canonical, but I've found that shorter questions are better on [so].  `os` is shorter than `subprocess`

Comment: If it was just supposed to be an example, `print 1234` (or `print(1234)`) would have been enough as well. But that's not the main pont of this all...

Answer (score 5):

Multiline statements may not start after a statement-separating `;` in Python – otherwise, there might be ambiguities about the code blocks.  Simply use line breaks in stead of `;`.  This "works" on Linux:

```
$ python -c "import os
while True: os.system('ls')"
```

Not sure how to enter this on Windows, but why not simply write the commands to a `.py` file if it's more than one line?

Comment: @MikePennington: If it's a one-time use, why don't you launch the interpreter and enter the commands there?

Comment: shell redirection and pipes, somewhat easier `bash` up-arrow editing if I make a mistake... and I'm still hooked on `perl -e` syntax from years of perl usage

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about windows, if all you want is to be able to type in one-liners, you could consider line breaks inside quotes:

```
% python -c "import os;
while (True):
  os.system('ls')"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really must do this in windows, you could use exec:

```
python -c "exec \"import os;\rwhile True:\r  os.system('dir')\""
```

(I substituted `dir` so it works on my windows system)